# How much humidity value underwater?

Tags: water, humidity

Stumbled upon this question this morning. Yet couldn't find the answer on google

If humidity is defined as ratio of water (vapor) content in air, what value will it show if we put the sensor underwater? assuming the sensor is waterproof

Will it be 100%? Or it simply give no reading as if using pH sensor to measure acidity of ambient air?

Comment: 1. *"If humidity is defined as ratio of water (vapor) content in air"*, then isn't "humidity underwater" obviously *undefined*? 2. What any particular sensor shows depends on its construction. I don't really understand in what way this is supposed to be a question about physics.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: This is just a more formal rephrasing of the age-old question: "Is water wet?"

Answer (score 4):

> humidity is defined as ratio of water (vapor) content in air

This definition is not complete. There are two definitions of humidity.

*Relative* humidity is the amount of moisture in the air relative to the maximum amount of water that air at the current temperature and pressure can hold, not how much water is present. Since it is a relative measurement, it is measured in percentage.

*Absolute* humidity is a measure of how much water there actually is and this is measured in physical units like mass of water per volume of air, not percentage.

> What value will it show if we put the sensor underwater?

It doesn't matter what value it shows because the sensor is not being used in a method where the physics are working as intended. The value is invalid. Like trying to use a stopwatch to measure weight. It doesn't matter what the stopwatch reads.

Answer (score 1):

Humidity sensors designed to work in air are not designed to work when immersed in water, so the reading produced by an immersed humidity meter will probably be meaningless- as is the concept of relative humidity in an airless environment to begin with.

But giving you the benefit of the doubt, let's assume the underwater humidity sensor has a bubble of air in it, and the sensor is touching that bubble.

The air inside the bubble will be quickly saturated with water vapor at whatever the ambient temperature happens to be, and thus it will always read 100% relative humidity.